# Custom 404 error page generates 403

Tags: iis

IIS 6.1 - Custom Error pages.
The web site is defined as www.url.com/mysite.  Custom error pages have been defined for mysite.  404 and 500.100.
I can redirect to /mysite/500.htm and /mysite/400.htm.
I can set 500.100 to redirect to /global/500.htm and this works.
When I redirect 404 to /global/404.htm I get a 403 access denied error.  (I also tried redirecting 404 to /global/500.htm just to make sure it was not file-specific rights.)

Directory browsing is enabled.

The page works if you browse directly to it.

Checked the iis log file for oddities.

Can anyone offer an explanation that might lead me in the right direction?

Comment: So if you load www.url.com/global/404.htm it works, and when you are sent there by redirect, you get a 403?

Comment: Correct.  Which has me wondering if the 403 is occurring before the redirect.  I'm stymied.

Comment: Remove the custom 404, then attempt to cause the error. Do you get the default 404?

Comment: Yes.  I do.  It also works if I redirect to www.url.com/mysite/404.htm

Comment: is the custom 404 thrown by your app or by global? Check if: 1 any authentication rules are inconsistent; 2 if you have a different app pool defined for global, 3 inconsistencies in global web.config/machine.config and your app web.config

Comment: Custom 404 is thrown by the app.  
Authentication consistent.  
Global is not set up as an app - it is a virtual directory.  Will be tomorrow before I can get the ok to change that.  

I have multiple apps www.url.com/site1, www.url.com/site2, www.url.com/site3 which are all configured as applications with their own app pools.  Ultimately I will want them all to redirect to the global error pages which will handle some error logging etc.  That being said, the web.config/machine.config files are all different, but expected to be.
Still odd that the 500 redirect works.

Comment: Take a look at this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318380 esp. the 403.1 - Execute access forbidden.  Also, it's possible that you exceed post size to the custom404 page.

Comment: I believe I have ruled out both of those issues by redirecting both the 500.100 and the 404 to the same file - which is basically <html>Test<html>.  Works for the 500.100 but not the 404.  It looks like the answer is going to be copying the redirect file to every site.  :-(